# Copy and paste from horizontal to vertial

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is a way to do what I want more automatically, i've been doing it with good old regular copy paste but it's taking a lot of time, I need to take the horizontal data I have currently and put it vertically while keeping the first column for each rows, the first column is my "main" part number and I need to link all the other numbers starting from column B to this main part number, example below,
I sometimes have hundreds of rows and columns to do this for, here is what i'm working with
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIyZv.png
And here's what the end result needs to look like;
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvxGh.png

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In Excel O365 you could use: `=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(CHOOSE({1;2},INDEX(A1,SEQUENCE(11)-(SEQUENCE(11)-1)),B1:L1)),"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved either with VBA Code or with formulas. I did it with formulas and will try to show you how below.

I have one sheet with all the data, lets call it **Sheet1**. It looks like this:
[image: Sheet1 with data]

Then, I have another sheet which returns what you want (**Sheet2**). It looks as follows:
[image: Solution]

Note that the first two columns are necesary for the formulas to work. The actual result is on Columns C and D.

Now, below are the formulas (or values) you would need to put in **Sheet2** to make it work:

- Cell A1: 0
- Cell B1: 1
- Cell A2: IF(B2=1,A1+1,A1)
- Cell B2: IF(B1+1=$G$1,1,B1+1)
- Cell C1: OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,A1,0)
- Cell D1: OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,A1,B1)
- Cell G1: The number of columns in the data on **Sheet1**
- Then, just drag the formulas (**not** the values in A1, B1), until you have the expected result.

I would suggest you try to implement this simple example first, and then move it to your actual spreadsheet.

Let me know how it goes.

**EDIT**: Regarding your comment, we could do a trick to make it work for a variable number of columns.

First, lets add some variability to the number of columns in **Sheet1**. This is how my new **Sheet1** looks like:

[image]

On **Sheet2** I added a formula to count the number of columns per row. See Column F below:
[image]

Then, the trick is to change the formulas in Column B in **Sheet2**:

- Before: Cell B2: IF(B1+1=$G$1,1,B1+1)
- After:  Cell B2: IF(B1+1=OFFSET($F$4,A1,0),1,B1+1)

Note: My formula to count the number of columns per row is:

- Cell F4: COUNTA(Sheet1!A1:D1)
- Note: Change D1 to the max column in **Sheet1**. Eg. M1.
- Note2: You can get rid of cell G1 now.

Comment: Hi Andres, this does work beautifully, it took me a few tries to really get it, I have only one problem maybe you can help me with. in my Sheet1 i've got multiple rows, some containing 7 columns, some 9, some 16, basically never the same, is there a way to adapt these formulas for this?

Comment: Hi @OlivierLepageDumont, I am glad it helped!. I just updated my answer to better fit your needs. Please consider marking the answer as correct :D.

Answer (score 0):

Start with column B and everything else becomes a doddle. I only use 1 formula for column B and no more than 1 or 2 for column A (there are 3-4+ methods, no need to duplicate yourself but choose any of them to construct A).

**I'm only using 1 formula to make each column.** Entire job task done in a minute-5.

**Column B. Do this first for all your "column B's":**'

```
=IF(ROW(A1)=1,INDEX(A$1:T$1,INT(((ROW()-20)/20+1-ROW($A$1))/COLUMNS(A$1:T$1))+1,MOD(ROW()-20-ROW($A$1),COLUMNS(A$1:T$1))+1),INDEX(A$1:T$1,INT(((ROW()-20)/20+1-ROW($A$1))/COLUMNS(A$1:T$1))+1,MOD(ROW()-20-ROW($A$1),COLUMNS(A$1:T$1))+1))
```

So all you have to do is drag down. Change only the row references to refer to your 100's if different rows you need to do this for. 1 minute. Job done

for 30 columns/cells change T to AD, for 200 cells , change T to GR, etc. You can also force it to stop at  number of your choice.

If you put it anywhere else, it will still work, but your going to have to jiggy with the math a bit to get it to start from the the first entry in the row ( or the specific Wherever you want). Its up to you.

It acts like a modular clock. Been using it for a few years. Ticker tape. Rolling slabs of concrete laying out for you.

here, this is what I get when I plug it into the first row of any column , referring to a 20 field length header on my sheet.

[image]

Etc... It continues forever (or for however long you want it). (and you can change the mod anytime).

The first argument you could change to whatever your requirements are , for instance , if(LEN(F8)<1, or whatever, to Start/"Set the clock."

And For any corresponding ranges (your first column for each) (** Your "Column A's" **):

`=IF(LEN(H20)<1,K21,H20)`

or you can use this logic. It Becomes elementary.

```
=IF(J21=K21,J21,J20)
```

Better if you use this starting from row 2 on each column A: if(and(j1=it's next door neighbour, row(it's next door neighbour cell=1)), it's self j1,..  blah blah blah blah

OR AM I MISSING THE POINT ?

**Method for getting column A;**

Since you already have B, A becomes a simple trivial matter. Like cell =$fixed$cell , i.e. A1=$B$1 and drag down.

simple. headache over. game over. Its all effortless.

But if you want me to elaborate more ,

**method 2 for getting **1st column, column A's**;**
=IF(LEN(AV1)>1,IF(ROW(AV1)=1,AV1,INDIRECT("Av"&1)),"")

**`=IF(ROW(B1)=1,B1,INDIRECT("B"&1))`**  <---- drag down from row 1

**Method 1 for getting **1st column****;

**`=IF(LEN(AV1)>1,$AV$1,"")`** <----- drag down from row 1

**Method 3, below was my favourite:**

**`=$B$1`** <---- **from row1** drag down (where row1 was just = column B, cell b1, **a1=b1**) easy peasy .

You could always demand a further simplification of M3:

**`A1`**=**`if(len(b1)>1,$b$1,"")`** <--drag down from b2 (where b1 was already set) *probably best because only returns a value as long as column B is .otherwise returns blank.

It's like handling duplicates by formula. Similar .

there was a method 4 too. bUt its late. (Written @ 02:00)

Or did I miss the point? It's easy. Imo

**Im only using 2 formulas. 1 for each column you need done . do column B first, and colimn A becomes a matter of fact . A doddle.**

**method 1 is my new favourite.**

Its late, my naighbours have pissed me off again. Pardon my fonts and writing  but seriously. didnt expect this. some people need to go to jail.(my naighbours)

So in the end: 1 formula for B. 1 for A (any one of any the 4+ methods. There are more also) , plug in and scroll for all the rows you need this done for . takes you 30 seconds? 5 minutes tops for all your rows.

Comment: i do think its marvelous. saves anyone a heck of time & since i developed it myself , (I haven't seen or found this free effortless looping functionality/ability anywhere else to transpose cells as you please) I am a bit nervous letting out out in public. pls keep it to yourself.. Maybe i am wrong. But i personally have not seen this anywhere else  as a formula (apart from the obvious abilities present in vba as a macro).